# Move focus to another display with keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, spaces

I'm using Yosemite. I have two external displays with several spaces (I like the idea one app per space).
Sometimes I want to move focus to another display without using a mouse. I have few solutions but they are not ideal.

- <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> *Move focus to next or another window* in System Preferences - it moves focus but mouse still stays on previous display so moving spaces does not work properly (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>or<kbd>→</kbd> moves spaces on previous display)
- BetterTouchTool can move mouse, but mouse position should be hardcoded. What is more moving a mouse does not cause moving the focus, you should click additionally and it's not always good
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> can move to *n* space, but it does not work if space is opened on another screen e.g. if space 1 is focused on display 1 and space 2 is opened on display 2 then pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> does not move focus, but pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> does (if space 3 is created on display 2)

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I found an app which does it - [Amethyst](http://ianyh.com/amethyst/). I've been looking for something like that for ages

Answer (score 5):

Summary:

1. Install  [hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org)
2. Copy the following code into init.lua and run hammerspoon
3. Press Cmd+1 to toggle between screens

For people who are looking for another solution to this, consider using hammerspoon (which is a great application that lets you write scripts for automating osx using lua). I've included the following code in my init.lua file to implement screen switching upon pressing Cmd+1.

```
local function focus_other_screen() -- focuses the other screen 
   local screen = hs.mouse.getCurrentScreen()
   local nextScreen = screen:next()
   local rect = nextScreen:fullFrame()
   local center = hs.geometry.rectMidPoint(rect)
   hs.mouse.setAbsolutePosition(center)
end 

function get_window_under_mouse() -- from https://gist.github.com/kizzx2/e542fa74b80b7563045a 
   local my_pos = hs.geometry.new(hs.mouse.getAbsolutePosition())
   local my_screen = hs.mouse.getCurrentScreen()
   return hs.fnutils.find(hs.window.orderedWindows(), function(w)
                 return my_screen == w:screen() and my_pos:inside(w:frame())
   end)
end

function activate_other_screen()
   focus_other_screen() 
   local win = get_window_under_mouse() 
   -- now activate that window 
   win:focus() 
end 

hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd"}, "1", function() -- does the keybinding
      activate_other_screen()
end)
```

This works by moving the mouse to the other screen, then focusing the application which is directly under the mouse. The code is in lua. Please see [hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org) for more details.